# Find a relationship between the present value and future value of an annuity

Tags: annuity, actuarial-science

The following is a previous examination question in Financial Mathematics:

> If $A, r, n, PV$ and $FV$ represents the ordinary annuity (annuity
>   immediate) amount, rate of interest, number of years, the present
>   value and the future value of the annuity respectively, find a
>   relationship between $PV$ and $FV$.

I need some help in illustrating this "relationship" as this question was allocated 6 marks.

I know that the present value of annuity immediate can be given by: $PV = K\left[ {\frac{{1 - {{\left( {1 + r} \right)}^{ - n}}}}{r}} \right]$ where $K$ is the amount per period; but how can this be used in this case?

Comment: This is a very elementary question. The relationship between the two is simply $FV=PV (1+r)^n$ as you can verify by comparing the formulas for FV and PV (or simply using common sense: a pound today is worth $(1+r)^n$ pounds n years hence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the annuity pays K every year from year 1 to n, you can write it’s PV as follows:

$PV=K \left( \frac{1}{1+r} +\frac{1}{(1+r)^2 }+ \dots + \frac{1}{(1+r)^n} \right)$

And FV, by noting that the first K is invested for n-1 periods, and the last one is received at n:

$FV=K \left( (1+r)^{n-1} + (1+r)^{n-2}+ \dots+ 1  \right) $

Now one just needs to compare the expressions on the right hand side of both equations. Multiplying PV by $(1+r)^n$ will then make the rhs of the first equal to that of the second equation, and hence:

$FV=PV \,(1+r)^n$